# What is Debugger PIN when I run the flask app python

Tags: python, flask

- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 620-122-212

I see this when I run the flask app and i'm trying to understand where it will get used?

Please let me know!

Comment: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/enabling-the-flask-interactive-debugger-in-development-with-gunicorn

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a security code for the debugger. Its purpose is to make access to the debugger more difficult for an attacker in a production environment. [More details here](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/debug/#debugger-pin)

Comment: Just a small correction, you should never be using `DEBUG` mode in `Production` at all.

Comment: Thank you. But I thought that I can use this PIN somewhere to debug what i'm doing actually, without adding logger into my program.

Comment: @dineshkumar yes you can use the `debugger` pin in the browser to launch the interactive debugger and look at various things.

Answer (score 26):

This is an additional security measure provided by `Werkzeug` (which is one of the dependencies for `Flask`) to prevent the debugger from being accessible without the knowledge of the `PIN`. You can use the debugger pin in the browser to launch the interactive debugger.

Please note you should never be using `DEBUG` mode in `Production` anyways because the stack trace of error can potentially reveal multiple aspects of your code.

The `Debugger PIN` is a just an added layer of security in case you inadvertently leave the `Debug` mode on in an `Production` application to make it difficult for the attacker to access the debugger .

Answer (score 19):

OP asked

> i'm trying to understand **where** it will get used?

and commented on the approved answer that he still wondering **where** to use the PIN to debug the program without adding a logger.

To any new viewers wondering where to access the debugger and use the PIN, it is accessible in the flask application at `/console`

A window requesting the PIN will pop up:
[image]

You can enter your PIN there, click `Confirm Pin`  and access the interactive console of your flask application. Please remember to turn OFF debug mode when deploying to production.

Comment: I believe this is the accurate answer

Comment: This IS the answer!

Comment: What is the point of this Flask/Werkzeug debug pin if you can't step thru the code?